# What PAT scope to pick in azure devops to get the yaml schema?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'd like to use the following endpoint:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/yamlschema/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I.e.

`https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/distributedtask/yamlschema`

For that I need to create a PAT with the appropriate access, only the docs do not list which scope I need to enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What PAT scope to pick in azure devops to get the yaml schema?

Based on my test , you could grant the **Token Administration(Read & manage)** or **Tokens(Read & manage)** permission to the PAT.

[image]

Then the Rest API could work fine.

Comment: This works! thanks. too bad I could not find more documentation on pat's and scopes - i could do with an overview of what scope gives access to what. Am i safe to assume the PAT is still quite restricted, so its not like these scopes give full access to all of azure devops or something?